# Auto select the value in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I applied a template on my product form and i would know how auto select the defined value in my edit form

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right: 10px;">
          <input id="bien_nb_piece_true" name="bien[nb_piece]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="0"/> Aucune
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right: 10px;">
          <input id="bien_nb_piece_true" name="bien[nb_piece]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="1"/> 1
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right: 10px;">
          <input id="bien_nb_piece_true" name="bien[nb_piece]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="2"/> 2
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right: 10px;">
          <input id="bien_nb_piece_true" name="bien[nb_piece]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="3"/> 3
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right: 10px;">
          <input id="bien_nb_piece_true" name="bien[nb_piece]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="4"/> 4
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-right: 10px;">
          <input id="bien_nb_piece_true" name="bien[nb_piece]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="5"/> 5 et +
        </label>
        </div>
```

If the value of my product is 1 i would like a active button on the 1

Comment: use `selected` attribute on the input type you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `checked` attribute, pivoting off of the value from the database/controller, like this:

```
<input <%= "checked" if product == 1 %> id="bien_nb_piece_true" name="bien[nb_piece]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="1"/>
<input <%= "checked" if product == 2 %> id="bien_nb_piece_true" name="bien[nb_piece]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="2"/>
<input <%= "checked" if product == 3 %> id="bien_nb_piece_true" name="bien[nb_piece]" type="radio" autocomplete="off" value="3"/>
```

And so on.